# What do informed/uninformed search algorithms return?

Tags: algorithm, search, artificial-intelligence

Do they return the path to a goal node?

Comment: Punctuation for readability

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you may be mixing-up [local search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_search_(constraint_satisfaction)) which is a general method for finding minima and maxima in optimization problems based on a loss-function, and [tree-based searches](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/csep573/11wi/lectures/03-hsearch.pdf) like informed search for finding a particular node in a tree based on some criteria.